# Doctrine Migrations: altering a column to be nullable in production

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I'm fairly new to Doctrine Migrations so apologies if this is really obvious.

**Updated to provide more information**

I have a Symfony2 entity mapping as below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;
```

This was added to a migration and deployed with everything working as it should. The column then needed to be updated to accept null values so it was changed to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
private $name;
```

The problem is that this has no impact on the resulting migration file:

```
$ php app/console cache:clear
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
$ tail -50 app/DoctrineMigrations/Version20131028205742.php

<?php

namespace Application\Migrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
class Version20131028205742 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql", "Migration can only be executed safely on 'mysql'.");

    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() != "mysql", "Migration can only be executed safely on 'mysql'.");

    }
}
```

No ALTER statements have been added to handle null values. I could drop and rebuild the database but as this specific migration has already been deployed this will result in problems in the production database. I can see this situation occurring again in the future so would like to understand it a bit more.

Is this a limitation of Doctrine and/or the Symfony2 Doctrine Migrations bundle? Is there a way to get around this without writing a custom migration?

Please note, all my other migrations are working fine, the only issue is adding nullable options to existing fields.

Comment: did you **clear your cache** before generating the diff? I think this should always be the first question to ask when doctrine mapping problems occur :D

Comment: yes I cleared the cache. I wouldn't have thought that was the route of my problem though as other entity updates were pulled through fine, just not the ALTER statements for nullables.

Comment: What do you mean by `resulting diff file`?

Comment: There will be no `diff file` - whatever that refers to. Your diff is what you've posted, you then run the `doctrine:schema:update` which will update your database.

Comment: When I say diff file I mean the file that is produced by the php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff command in app/DoctrineMigrations

Comment: As I said in my answer: if you rebuild your db after you change the entity, the diff will be empty because db schema fits to entity metadata. Try this experiment: 1) rollback your entity to nullable=false 2) rebuild your db 3) change your entity to nullable=true 4) run diff (without rebuilding db). Now the diff should contain an appropriate alter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doctrine's diff works in that way it compares your entities metadata with existing database schema. So if you run `doctrine:schema:update` **after** you've ran the migration - doctrine doesn't notice any change because db schema is already changed (and therefore fits to entites metadata). And basically after you run the migration you don't need to run `update` anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I hadn't rebuilt the database and I thought I'd only used the diff and migrate commands but after rolling back a bit and following your steps I got it working. I'm guessing at some point that I must have run the commands in the wrong order and screwed something up.